# Equivalent of restrict: AE in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular

In Angular 1, you could use `restrict` to determine how your directive could be used. For example:

```
angular.module('foo').directive('fooDirective', [function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    /* ... */
  }
}]);
```

And then you would be able to use this in your template either as an attribute or as an element:

```
<foo />
```

**OR**

```
<div foo />
```

I've been reading on sites such as [this one](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html) that in Angular2, the `select` proper way to define how your component is used now:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'Sample'
});
```

Then in your template:

```
<Sample />
```

Similarly, adding brackets allows it to be used as an attribute:

```
@Component({
  selector: '[Sample]'
});
```

Template:

```
<div Sample />
```

But what if I want to allow it to be used both as an attribute and as an element, the equivalent of `restrict: 'AE'` in Angular 1?

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
@Component({
  selector: 'sample,[Sample]'
});
```

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/60727c4d2ba1e4b0b9455c767d0ef152bcedc7c2/modules/angular2/src/common/forms/directives/ng_form.ts#L81 for an example

> `@Directive({
>     selector: 'form:not([ngNoForm]):not([ngFormModel]),ngForm,[ngForm]',`

Answer (score 0):

`restrict: 'AE'` is still valid in `AngularJS 2`. What you are referring to is `Angular 2 for TypeScript`. I don't see `TypeScript` tag in your question. [Go to the link you have provided](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html) and notice that `Angular 2 for TypeScript` is selected in drop-down.

[image]

Comment: Apologies, yes, I was using Typescript.